# Editing the PDF to add/modify contents

Tags: javascript, pdf

Currently in my application users can view or download the PDF files. Displaying the PDF call is an API call to a third party site. Below is the way i am getting the PDF and displaying it using `window.open`:

```
window.open(URL,"null","width=0, height=0");
```

What I need is to add or modify the contents in PDF. How can I achieve this?.

I guess I have failed to explain my problem. Let me explain this in detail. As mentioned earlier  the PDF which the user will be seeing is from the the third party site. We fetch the PDF and display in new window to user using `window.open`. Now I need to add some detail into the PDF and also edit the contents like changing the font size etc. What should be the approach? Do I need to save the PDF on the server and then modify the contents and display it to user? Or can I edit directly without saving it? I am not sure how to approach this. Kindly help.

I have tried out many questions on this forum but unfortunately I did not get the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit and update the pdf file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892361/how-to-edit-and-update-the-pdf-file)

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.